# Trivial C++ program not writing to file

Tags: c++

These lines are the sole contents of main():

```
fstream file = fstream("test.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
string word;
while (file >> word) { cout << word + " "; }
file.seekp(ios::beg);
file << "testing";
file.close();
```

The program correctly outputs the contents of the file (which are "the angry dog"), but when I open the file afterwards, it still just says "the angry dog", not "testingry dog" like I would expect it to.

Full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file = fstream("test.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
    string word;
    while (file >> word) { cout << word + " "; }
    file.seekp(ios::beg);
    file << "testing";
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: If the program is so short, why didn't you post ALL of it?

Comment: I figured it was best to shave off everything unnecessary so as to make it more readable. But, sure.

Comment: I am surprised it compiles. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm just compiling it in Visual C++ 2010 Express. Why, what's wrong with it?

Comment: The way you initialize the fstream. See @Nemo's answer. But it isn't relevant to the problem you report.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two bugs in your code.

First, `iostream` has no copy constructor, so (strictly speaking) you cannot initialize `file` the way you do.

Second, once you run off the end of the file, `eofbit` is set and you need to clear that flag before you can use the stream again.

```
fstream file("test.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::out);
string word;
while (file >> word) { cout << word + " "; }
file.clear();
file.seekp(ios::beg);
file << "testing";
file.close();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'll go look up what a copy constructor is now, I guess.